# Zigzag indicator for stock prices

Tags: python, pandas

I have read on SO and replicated an indicator for stock prices that works as intended. It's called ZigZag and projects peaks and valleys on historical prices. I pass a pandas dataframe with OHLC prices to my ZigZag class.

My problem is that it runs really slow, I have about 70 stocks with 10k rows each. takes about a minute and a half, but the dataset and number of stocks are increasing rapidly.

Can you see anything that could improve first of all execution speed?

Other comments for code/structure improvement also welcome.

```
class Zigzag:

    def __init__(self, timeseries, swingthresh = 0.03):

        self.timeseries = timeseries
        self.swingthresh = swingthresh #0.03 default, can pass value to change zigzag indikator
        self.upswing = None
        self.zigzag = []
        

    def add_row(self, list):

        self.zigzag.append(list)
        self.upswing = True if list[-1] == 'high' else False

    def update_row(self, timestamp, price):

        #uppdates last row
        self.zigzag[-1][0], self.zigzag[-1][1] = timestamp, price

    def first_swing(self):

        lasthigh, lastlow = self.timeseries.iat[0,1], self.timeseries.iat[0,2]
        
        for index, row in self.timeseries.iterrows():

            row_high, row_low = row['high'], row['low']

            high = row['high'] > lastlow + (lastlow * self.swingthresh)
            low = row['low'] < lasthigh - (lasthigh * self.swingthresh)

            if high & low:

                lasthigh = row_high
                lastlow = row_low

            else:

                self.upswing = True if high ==True else False
                return

    def get_swings(self):

        self.first_swing()
        #Config
        
        lasthigh, lastlow = self.timeseries.iat[0,1], self.timeseries.iat[0,2]

        #setting first order based on first swing
        if self.upswing == True:

            self.add_row([self.timeseries.index[0], lastlow, 'low'])
            self.add_row([self.timeseries.index[0], lasthigh, 'high'])
    
        else:

            self.add_row([self.timeseries.index[0], lasthigh, 'high'])
            self.add_row([self.timeseries.index[0], lastlow, 'low'])
        
        for index, row in self.timeseries.iterrows():

            row_timestamp = index
            row_high = row['high']
            row_low = row['low']

            if self.upswing == True:
                if row_high > lasthigh:

                    self.update_row(index, row_high)
                    lasthigh = row_high


                if row_low <= lasthigh - (lasthigh * self.swingthresh):
                    #if new swinglow, add new row
                    self.add_row([row_timestamp, row_low, 'low'])
                    lastlow = row_low

            else: 
                #in downswing
                    if row_low < lastlow:
                        
                        self.update_row(index, row_low)
                        lastlow = row_low
                        

                    if row_high >= lastlow + (lastlow * self.swingthresh):
                        
                        self.add_row([row_timestamp, row_high, 'high'])
                        lasthigh = row_high

        return self.zigzag
```

Comment: You forget about Depth and BackStep in your code.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use the code?